# Transmission Line Model, Symmetric vs Unsymmetric

Tags: transmission-line

---

Can someone please explain what's the difference between a symmetric vs unsymmetric  transmission line model ?

The normal un-symmetric one has R and L in series with G, C in parallel. While the symmetric model has the R and L divided in two halves and distributed on the two sides of the parallel G and C.
[image: Unsymmetric]

[image: Symmetric]

Is there any advantage what so ever of representing the same thing two different ways? We can get to the telegrapher's equations either way, so what's the point? Is it that the transmission line model should represent the line as being same from either point?

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no difference, in fact four different circuits could be used, the L and the T depicted in the question and the Pi and the inverted L.

All of them are equivalent.

You have two constitutive equations, one for the the voltage drop and the other for the shunt current.

Taking for instance this L diagram

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxWCuM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and writing  the current change along the x direction we have
$$ i(x)-i(x+\mathrm{d}x) = G\,\mathrm{d}x\;v(x+\mathrm{d}x)+C\,\mathrm{d}x\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(x+\mathrm{d}x)$$

then we substitute for  removing v(x+dx)
$$v(x+\mathrm{d}x)=v(x)-R\,\mathrm{d}x\;i(x)-L\,\mathrm{d}x\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}i(x)$$

we get

$$ 
\begin{align} 
i(x)-i(x+\mathrm{d}x) &= G\,\mathrm{d}x\left(v(x)-R\,\mathrm{d}x\;i(x)-L\,\mathrm{d}x\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}i(x)\right)+\\ &+C\,\mathrm{d}x\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(v(x)-R\,\mathrm{d}x\;i(x)-L\,\mathrm{d}x\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}i(x)\right)
\end{align}$$

$$ 
\begin{align} 
i(x)-i(x+\mathrm{d}x) &= G\,\mathrm{d}x \;v(x)
-\left(RG\;i(x)+LG\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}i(x)\right)(\mathrm{d}x)^2+
\\ &+C\,\mathrm{d}x\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(x)-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(RC\;i(x)+LC\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}i(x)\right)(\mathrm{d}x)^2
\end{align}$$

so, in turn, we have terms proportional to dx while those proportional to dx squared, are more infinitesimal and has then to be neglected.

$$(\mathrm{d}x)^2=\omicron(\mathrm{d}x) $$

and finally

$$i(x)-i(x+\mathrm{d}x)=G\,\mathrm{d}x \;v(x)+C\,\mathrm{d}x\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(x)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i(x,t)=G \,v(x,t)+C\,\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(x,t)$$

The same applies to the voltage drop and shunt current for thr L and inverted L circuits and, possibly with some more boring algebra, to the T and Pi versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in relation to ground / common signal.
For example asymmetrical TL is realized by coaxial cable where the shield is grounded.
Symmetrical TL can be realized by "twisted pair" or "open  twin lead" where neither signal path is directly grounded / has same relation to ground.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you please elaborate a little bit ? How does distributing the elements change the relation to the ground? I've added pictures of the models to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

One is only meaningful when driven from one end, the other can be driven from both ends with the same effect (talking about voltage sources, but not necessarily only them). In terms of derivation, sure, one is redundant; in terms of simulation, it's a different thing.